# Does damage from Caltrops with Jagged Spikes stack?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

As a Demon Hunter, if you place multiple [Caltrops with Jagged Spikes rune](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/active/caltrops) on the same spot, does the damage of each one stack? Or does the monster just receive the 45% weapon damage during the trap lifetime?

Comment: I believe the monster receives damage when they trigger the trap, allowing stacking, but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't actually tested this specific combination, but it should work the same way as Spike Trap, eg. if you place down 10 Caltrops on the same spot as soon as a monster enters that area then they should get hit by 10x 45% weapon damage, or a bit less than 2 Spike Traps worth of damage. For what it is, it probably isn't an efficient use of your discipline, though it should stack just fine.

Comment: Considering that you can only lay 5 Caltrops, it won't hurt your discipline that much.

Comment: @MBraedley: I wasn't even aware there was a limit on how many you could lay. I usually use the rooting rune, so laying too many isn't really effective.

Comment: I don't think it lists it, but don't seem to be able to lay more than that.

Comment: @Nathew, you can only have 5 untriggered ones. But if you lay down caltrops ontop of already triggered ones they don't despawn. you can get more than 5 on one spot (so you can get that 10 at which point the dmg no longer stacks).

Answer (score -1):

With the perk passive "perfectionist" you can lay up to 5... but the limiting factor is discipline.

Combined with an ability or passive that assists discipline regeneration the sky is the limit.

Comment: You still can't lay more than 5. After the first 5, they start despawning when you lay more, similar to Spike Trap. I did actually test this.